# How do I solve the conflict caused by my jQuery navigation plugin and javaScript file?

Tags: conflict

My jQuery navigation works- but now it's conflicting with a fadeIn and fadeOut effect (picture and greeting) so they are not showing up.

Here is a link to my page:http://bit.ly/1cr93gD

Here is the code that is on my final_project.js file for the fadeIn & fadeOut effects:

```
   jQuery$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#headshot').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(5000);
   $('#greeting').css('visibility','visible').hide().toggle(9000);

    var defaultH1 = parseInt($('h1').css('font-size')); 
    var defaultP = parseInt($('p').css('font-size'));   
    var count = 0;  
    var elements = ['p', 'h1'];

    $('.minus').click(function(){
if ( count >= -1 ) {
    $(elements).each(function(key, val) {
        $(val).css('font-size', parseInt($(val).css('font-size'))-2);
    });
    count--;
};
    });

    $('.plus').click(function(){
if ( count <= 1 ) {
    $(elements).each(function(key, val) {
        $(val).css('font-size', parseInt($(val).css('font-size'))+2);
    });
    count++;
 };
    });

    $('.reset').click(function(){
$('h1').css('font-size', defaultH1);
$('p').css('font-size', defaultP);
count = 0;
}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code has been tested it had some syntax error I have corrected it and it works fine, bellow is Working code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#headshot').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(5000);
   $('#greeting').css('visibility','visible').hide().toggle(9000);

    var defaultH1 = parseInt($('h1').css('font-size')); 
    var defaultP = parseInt($('p').css('font-size'));   
    var count = 0;  
    var elements = ['p', 'h1'];

    $('.minus').click(function(){
if ( count >= -1 ) {
    $(elements).each(function(key, val) {
        $(val).css('font-size', parseInt($(val).css('font-size'))-2);
    });
    count--;
};
    });

    $('.plus').click(function(){
if ( count <= 1 ) {
    $(elements).each(function(key, val) {
        $(val).css('font-size', parseInt($(val).css('font-size'))+2);
    });
    count++;
 };
    });

    $('.reset').click(function(){
$('h1').css('font-size', defaultH1);
$('p').css('font-size', defaultP);
count = 0;
})
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing the code</h1>
<button class="minus"> - </button>
<button class="plus"> + </button>
<button class="reset"> reset </button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1 id="greeting">Welcome</H1>
<img src="http://www.kveller.com/mayim-bialik/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/mayim-bialik-headshot-cropped.jpg" id="headshot"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

if you what to toggle between entities then look at bellow example to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#headshot').fadeOut(000);
   $('#greeting').fadeOut(5000);
   $('#headshot').fadeIn(5000);
   setInterval(function(){
          $('#headshot').fadeOut(5000);
          $('#greeting').fadeIn(5000);
   },10000);
 setTimeout(function(){
         setInterval(function(){
               $('#headshot').fadeIn(5000);
               $('#greeting').fadeOut(5000);
         },10000);
   },5000); 
 });
</script>
<style>
#greeting,#headshot {position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;}  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="greeting" >Welcome</H1>
<img src="http://www.kveller.com/mayim-bialik/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/mayim-bialik-headshot-cropped.jpg" id="headshot" width="200px" height="200px"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

in this case both entities can be of same or different type.